# Prolog list binding

Tags: prolog

Hi i'm having huge trouble with Prolog, I have tried loads of driffernt ways of trying to get the [Code in this link](http://jsbin.com/neramisemu/1/edit?html) working but I just cant get the outcome no matter what I try and trying to figure out how lists work is a nightmare that I just cant get my head around.

That being said the output i'm getting from the following code I like, the problem is getting the bindings with TeachersGroup and TeachersClass. 
What i'm trying to do for example if GroupClass = 'AI' then TeachersClass should be 'AI' and leave out Games_Design as Bsc4 don't do Games_Design (but Bsc1 do hence why its there).

```
whoTeachBsc4(GroupID,GroupStream,GroupStudents,GroupClass,GroupsTeachers,GroupSize
,TeacherID,TeachersName,TeachersGroup,TeachersClass):-

groups(GroupID,GroupStream,GroupStudents,GroupClass,GroupsTeachers,GroupSize)
```

I guess another way to word what I want is how do I manipulate the lists to only output what I want.

Comment: A good way to become familiar with the basics of lists is to work through the relevant problems in 99-Prolog Problems: https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems/1.

Comment: You have deeper problems than just Prolog lists; for example, the first sentence of your question goes on and on, without proper punctuation.... I guess a "run-on sentence" is the correct term. Similarly, your code has lines that do not fit in 80 columns, or on my screen, and you have a predicate with 10 arguments. These things do not make it incorrect, but it makes your English and your Prolog difficult to understand, or correct.